# How to get the itemcount using SOAP

Tags: sharepoint

How to get the ItemCount for a ListCollection, without actually getting all the list items in SharePoint using SOAP?

Is there a SOAP webservice for that?

Comment: Even thoug you have marked an answer, check if SPList.ItemCount works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the total number of items in a List/Library, you can use the [GetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist%28office.12%29.aspx) method to get `ItemCount`.

Comment: That's nice. That will work. Is there a way to get only the itemCount line from the response of GetList, and avoid all other data?

Comment: You'll need to get all of the list's data to get the count.

Answer (score 0):

As per SharePoint 2010 SDK, if you want count of all items in the list, SPList.ItemCount would perform faster than SPList.Items.Count.

Comment: In vijay's question he specified using SOAP (web services).. not the SharePoint API.

Comment: yes Ashish, I am looking only at SOAP, primarily to be used from a Java app. Kit's answer solved me the problem.